# Blank pages in some versions of Acrobat

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat

I have a PDF that is being generated from HTML source using HTMLDOC.  While I am able to view the file fine on my mac, and on every version of Acrobot that I can get my hands on, some end users are showing some pages as completely blank.

The blank pages are somewhat unique in that they do contain images, but I do not see why this would effect the output.

Are there any known bugs with Adobe Reader that might cause this?

Edit:
Dug through this, have the originals from a logged copy, and whilt it works on my end, I still have clients complaining.

Comment: Have you tried checking the adobe version on the client machines because if it is happening for the same people all the time it could be their machines but if it happens at random it might be a bug.

Comment: I've tried this with a few different versions that I can get from Adobe, and none recreated the issue.  This issue is quite elusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is there are fonts in the file that aren't on the client's machine.  Are the fonts embedded? If not, that would be the first thing I would try.  It will make your PDFs bigger, but should fix the problem.

Comment: This works in some cases, so I'll give you the nod.  But it doesn't work in every case.

Comment: It has been 11 years since I did any work with PDF internals, but I'm pretty bored, so if you send me a sample I'll have a look at it.  I can't promise I'll know any more from looking, but I'll have a look.

Comment: We haven't had any reported incidents in a year or so.  I was mostly just getting my accept % up.  =-]

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this....after opening PDF balank page is displayed. But after I scroll to next page and come back, the text is shown.